# Javascript não funciona no localhost mas funciona no servidor

Tags: php, javascript, angular, xampp

Tenho um projeto que possui um gráfico gerado por javascript e angular logo na home page após um login, porém, no meu localhost esse gráfico nunca foi mostrado e cheguei em uma parte do trabalho em que preciso mexer nele, porém, sem ver fica difícil. Porém, o que está online no servidor funciona normalmente, mas somente o Local não funciona, já puxei os arquivos direto do servidor pra minha máquina e ele simplesmente não mostra! Alguém tem alguma solução?

Eu já limpei cache, já modifiquei algumas configurações do google chrome e firefox (Não funciona em nenhum deles e nem no Microsoft Edge), já mudei as linhas que chamam os arquivos pro topo como vi em alguns lugares mas nada de resolver.

Links chamados no meu projeto.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.min.js"></script>

<script src="<?php echo $portal_path;?>assets/js/site/angular-chart.min.js"></script>

<script src="<?php echo $portal_path;?>assets/js/site/circleOfLifeChart2.js"></script>

<script src="https://rawgit.com/beaver71/Chart.PieceLabel.js/master/build/Chart.PieceLabel.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $portal_path;?>assets/css/site/sliderCircleOfLife.css">
```

No inspect do Google Chrome, vejo vários erros que acontecem no Localhost mas não acontecem no servidor.
Eu utilizo o XAMPP.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Como você está abrindo o seu arquivo HTML? Dando dois cliques no arquivo ou servindo através de um servidor local?

Comment: `vejo vários erros que acontecem no Localhost`.. seria interessante editar a pergunta e incluir esses erros

Comment: Depois tenta criar um servidor com o próprio `php`. Como por exemplo, `php -S localhost:8080`. Talvez o erro esteja na configuração do XAMPP

Comment: O que ele exibe no console?
A variável $portal_path remete ao seu arquivo local? O que ela retorna?

Comment: @fernandosavio eu estou usando através do localhost, localhost/CoLWithGit que é o nome do projeto.

Comment: Estou editando a pergunta com os erros que aparecem no console

Comment: @Bruno sim, o ela está assim   "$portal_path = "//" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . "/CoLWithGit/";"

Comment: Os erros estão na postagem, obrigado pela atenção de todos!

Comment: O que eu quero que rode é o CircleOfLifeChart, na máquina do meu chefe ele funciona, na minha e do outro programador não. Um detalhe, que eu não sei se tem alguma configuração de banco de dados, pois o meu o usuário e senha do banco de dados é diferente do dele